# How to suppress the android-room warning: Primary key constraint on id is ignored when being merged into Foo

Tags: android-room

When using Android android-architecture-component **room** library, and I set a `@Embedded(prefix = "xxx_")` to a Class field, got the warning after every build:

[image]

How to suppress the warning: Primary key constraint on `id` is ignored when being merged into Foo

Thanks!

Comment: Related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70994488

Answer (score 29):

You can suppress that warning adding this annotation to your class:

```
@SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.PRIMARY_KEY_FROM_EMBEDDED_IS_DROPPED)
```

In your case it's the `History` class.

Comment: Do you want to share any explanation about why ignoring the problem is the solution here?